PSQL fire change on view change
I have a case similar to this simplified one:
I have a table users with unique column username, and lots of other columns, including nullable boolean manual_override.
There is also a somewhat complexly defined view myview with columns username that corresponds to users table and column active which can be true or false.
What i'd like to have is new view, myview_final, which will be the same as myview, except when manual_override fields is not null - in that case, I'd like to se it to manual_override. But also, even if maunal_override exists, I'd like for myview_final to default back to myview, whenever the value in myview changes - from true to false or vice-versa, for any specific user. Similarly, I could set the manual_override to null for certain  user when their corresponding row in myview changes.
Note that active field in myview depends on a lot of things, including timestamps in database.
Is this even possible? I realise view is not material, so "change in view" might not be well defined for all the cases. In my case I feel it should be possible, as I could just write a lot of triggers that will effectively catch the change in view, but that feels like code duplication. I've seen here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html that certain triggers on views are possible but didn't understand exactly how does it apply to this (moderately) simple scenario.
Any thoughts appreciated!
